# How can I create a live-updating bound text input in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dialog, electron

I am creating a native app with angular and electron, and right now I am trying to get the user to chose a path for creating a folder. I have two separate text boxes, one for the name of the folder and the other for the path (which is bound to the output of an electron dialog). I want to have the value of the path input be bound to both the name and the path. For example, when the user starts typing into the name box, the text is appended to the value of the path box, to show the final folder that will be created. How could I do this?

I have tried using angular's keyup binding, but I can't figure out how to change the value of the path input. I have also tried using interpolation, but it only updates when a new path is chosen through the dialog, and when there is nothing in the name field, it shows up as undefined.

This is my component html:

```
<input #name type="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
<input #path type="text" value="{{ this.pathChosen + name.value }}"><button (click)="this.pathChosen = this.getPath()"><img src="assets/folder-icon.svg"></button><br>
<button>Create</button>
```

I want the box to be live-updating, like the example at the bottom of the page in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind, but that seems only to work in AngularJS, and instead of adding to a text element, it does not show how to add to an input element (the example uses a span element to interpolate). If anyone knows how this can be done, I really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of looking at angularjs documentation, why aren't you looking at the angular documentation?

Comment: Start by looking at: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax Then go through the tutorial to learn the basics of angular :) https://angular.io/start

Comment: @AJT82, I was not looking at the AngularJS documentation specifically, I was just searching for answers to this question, and that was the one result related to angular and had a good example. Thank you for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<input #name type="name" placeholder="Name (input)="name.value=$event.target.value"><br>
<input #path type="text" [value]="this.pathChosen + name.value"><button (click)="this.pathChosen = this.getPath()"><img src="assets/folder-icon.svg"></button><br>
<button>Create</button>
```

you need to update the value of the input variable 'name'.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I haven't had time to test this because I found a way to do this with form control, but I will test your suggestion as soon as I get a chance.